# ReactJS | How do I get the response when the API hit process is successful?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

This is function when hit api

> function click to triger

```
const  _selectBranch = async () => {
    const { user, } = props;
       await props.fetchGetBranchList(user.tokenResponse.accessToken, user.customerCode);
       const { branchList } = props;
       console.log(branchList)
  }
```

this action dispatch

```
 export const getBranchList = (token, code) => async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: BRANCH_LIST_REQ,
        });
        try {
            const res = await apiBranch(token).listBranchGet(code);
            if(res.data != null){
                dispatch({
                    type: BRANCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
                    payload: { data: res.data },
                });
            }    
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: BRANCH_LIST_FAILED,
                payload: error
            });
        }
    };
```

my reducers

```
    const initialState = {
        branchList: null, 
    };
    
    export const listNews = (state = { ...initialState }, action) => {
        const { payload, type } = action;
        switch (type) {
             case BRANCH_LIST_REQ: {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    branchList: null
                };
            }
            case BRANCH_LIST_SUCCESS: {
                const { data } = payload;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    branchList: data
                };
            }
           default:
               return state;
    }
};
```

I succeeded in getting a response, if I use useEffect
this code

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(props.branchList){
          setStorage("PO_ACTIVE", purchaseOrder);
          props.push('/Home/BucketList/', props.branchList.cartId)
        } 
},[props.branchList]);
```

but I want to get a response in the process of this code, but if I use this code the response I get is always null

```
const  _selectBranch = async () => {
        const { user, } = props;
           await props.fetchGetBranchList(user);
const { branchList } = props;
          if(branchList != null ){
              setStorage("PO_ACTIVE", purchaseOrder);
              props.push('/Home/BucketList/', props.branchList.cartId)
            } 
               console.log(branchList)
          }
```